# Всплывающий текст с помощью jQuery при select value='0'

Tags: html, jquery

Есть список и кнопка. Как можно сделать при помощи jQuery так, чтобы появлялось всплывающее предупреждение `<p id="warn">Warning</p>`, когда мы кликаем на кнопку, при хоть одном `select` со значением `value='0' ?`

```css
#warn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="length" name="length">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="weight" name="weight">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="height" name="height">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<p id="warn">Warning</p>

<button id="button">Result</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var selectLength = $("#length");
var selectWeight = $("#weight");
var selectHeight = $("#height");
var warn = $("#warn");
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  if(!!!selectLength.val() || !!!selectWeight.val() || !!!selectHeight.val() ) {
    warn.css("display", "inline-block");
  } else {
    warn.css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
#warn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="length" name="length">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="weight" name="weight">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="height" name="height">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<p id="warn">Warning</p>

<button id="button">Result</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для селектов лучше присвоить один класс - так выборка проще

```js
var $select = $('select');
$select.on('change', function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
    $this.val() && $this.removeClass('select_error') 
})
$('#button').on('click', function(e){
  $select.each(function(i, el) {
    var $this = $(el);
    !$this.val() && $this.addClass('select_error') 
  })
})
```

```css
#warn {
  display: none;
}
.select_error {
  border-color: red
}
.select_error ~ #warn {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="length" name="length">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="weight" name="weight">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="height" name="height">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<p id="warn">Warning</p>

<button id="button">Result</button>
 Выполнить код
```

Также при ошибки можно давать один общий класс. Зависит от структуры кода